# The term 'pipx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, brownie, pipx

I have followed the instructions to install Brownie on Visual studio code of their website.

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipx

python3 -m pipx ensurepath
```

The 2 lines above poses no problem. I restarted the terminal to input line:

```
pipx install eth-brownie
```

*pipx : The term 'pipx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

Was wondering what went wrong. Any form of assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you don't have the python binary Folder in your path variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your environment variables.
python3 -m pipx ensurepath adds the directories to PATH, but they are added in all lowercase for some reason. Fix the directory paths to match the case.

Comment: python -m pipx ensurepath adds the path string to PATH in lowercase. That is the issue

Answer (score 4):

I run `py -m pipx install eth-brownie` or python3 -m pipx install eth-brownie`

Answer (score 4):

I checked my PATH after running `python3 -m pipx ensurepath` and, despite the error message, noticed the paths had not actually been added.  adding them manually, followed by closing and reopening vscode, seemed to solve it for me.  hope this helps anyone...

Comment: WOW it is so good!

Answer (score 2):

Use can use pip instead :

**pip install eth-brownie**

then:

**git clone https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.git
cd brownie
python3 setup.py install**

u r done !!

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++ build tools installed via Build Tools for Visual Studio ([Visual CPP build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)),
you may have to run this command: 
`pip install --upgrade setuptools` 
and then repeat the installation process and restart your computer. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

closing and re-opening the terminal gave me the same error. I completely closed my VScode and opened it, and then it worked.